# How to get N of product into equation (or so)

Tags: maximum-likelihood, linear-algebra

Can somebody explain how this works or direct me to a rule that describes this simplification? I understand the whole process but how the '*getting the $n$ in front to $\lambda$*' works is unclear to me.

$p(x_1,...,x_n|\lambda) = \prod_{i=1}^{n}\frac{\lambda^{x_i}e^{-\lambda}}{x_i!}$

$\log(p(x_1,...,x_n|\lambda)) = \left(\sum^n_{i=1}x_i\right) \log(\lambda) - n\lambda $

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you multiply $\exp(-\lambda)$ $n$ times, you get $\exp(-n \lambda)$. So when you take the natural log that term becomes $-n \lambda$.